# keycloak apache server configuration with 'Mixed Content' problems

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf, mod-proxy, keycloak

have a problems configuring keycloak behind my apache server,

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://dev.mydomain.com/auth/admin/master/console/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
>   'http://dev.mydomain.com/auth/resources/1.7.0.final/admin/keycloak/js/controllers/groups.js'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

My apache configuration is,

```
ServerName dev.mydomain.com 
ServerAdmin dev@mydomain.com



SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /opt/mydomain/domains/dev.mydomain.com/apache/dev.mydomain.com.crt 
SSLCertificateKeyFile /opt/mydomain/domains/dev.mydomain.com/apache/dev.mydomain.com.key 
SSLCertificateChainFile /opt/mydomain/domains/dev.mydomain.com/apache/dev.mydomain.com.ca-bundle


DocumentRoot /opt/mydomain/domains/dev.mydomain.com/apache/htdocs

<Directory /opt/mydomain/domains/dev.mydomain.com/apache/htdocs>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPreserveHost On
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"

<Proxy  https://dev.mydomain.com/*  >
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from all
 </Proxy>



ProxyPass /auth http://localhost:10082/auth nocanon
ProxyPassReverse /auth http://localhost:10082/auth
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 7):

You'll also need to update Wildfly configuration as outlined in [Enable SSL on a Reverse Proxy -> Configure WildFly](http://keycloak.github.io/docs/userguide/keycloak-server/html/server-installation.html)

If you look for a Wildfly CLI configuration, [have a look here](https://github.com/dukecon/keycloak_postgres_https):

```
$ jboss-cli.sh -standalone --file=batch.cli

# batch.cli
embed-server --std-out=echo
batch
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=default:write-attribute(name=proxy-address-forwarding,value=true)
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=default:write-attribute(name=redirect-socket,value=proxy-https)
/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/socket-binding=proxy-https:add(port=443)
run-batch
stop-embedded-server
```