# {{notification.header}} {{notification.message}} loading while accessing Keycloak Admin console

Tags: java, nginx, jboss, keycloak, jboss-tools

We initially had a dockerized 1.9.3 keycloak running on a virtual machine with us able to access Admin console. We had to later abandon this VM but we ended up cloning another VM with all the contents on it.

The dockerized keycloak is running behind a reverse proxy NGINX which is passing all the required headers per the below thread

http://keycloak-user.88327.x6.nabble.com/keycloak-user-ssl-apache2-difficulties-td1570.html

```
 RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https" 
 RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
```

I've tried a bunch of different things but no matter what i do I am running into the below error when I try accessing the Keycloak admin console

```
   {{notification.header}} {{notification.message}} loading....
```

Appreciate any help -

Comment: Below solution in thread fixed it for me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35169503/keycloak-apache-server-configuration-with-mixed-content-problems/35246094#35246094

Answer (score 2):

You need to acces the database, table REALM and set the columns *_theme to null in order to load default theme:

```
update REALM set ACCOUNT_THEME = null, ADMIN_THEME = null, LOGIN_THEME = null where id = 'your-realm-name'
```

Answer (score 1):

Which navigate this using ?!

This same error appeared to me when accessing the keycloak admin console. But this only happens when you use the Internet Explorer browser.

Resolved when using Google Chrome browser.